# Capturing STDERR

Tags: perl

I'm trying to capture only STDERR when running this command

```
my @output = `cleartool setview -exec "cd $myPath; $myBuildCommand" $myView 1>/dev/null`;
```

However, I always get both STDERR and STDOUT in @output.

I'm trying to catch the warnings and errors from running $myBuildCommand. Any ides?

Answer (score 3):

Redirect STDERR to STDOUT before redirecting STDOUT to `/dev/null`. Order is important!

```
my $stderr = `some-command 2>&1 > /dev/null`;
```

If you reverse the order of redirections then both STDERR and STDOUT end up in `/dev/null`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. However, I must still be doing something wrong. I think I'm redirecting something else, becouse @output always gets both STDERR and STDOUT

Comment: Your original question only shows you redirecting STDOUT, not STDERR. BTW, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html lists examples for capturing STDERR but not STDOUT (look for `qx` or `backtick`).

Comment: I trying to do this just from the command line: ls 2>&1 1>/dev/null    gives me "Ambiguous output redirect

Answer (score 3):

To capture a command's STDERR but discard its STDOUT (ordering is important here):

```
 my @output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
```

See also [How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command?) in perlfaq8.

Comment: I trying to do this just from the command line: ls 2>&1 1>/dev/null gives me "Ambiguous output redirect"

Comment: @user1758367 "Ambiguous redirect" implies that you are using csh.  csh does not provide a sane mechanism for separating stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do any sort of non-trivial command capturing you almost certainly wanted `IPC::Run`.

```
use IPC::Run 'run';

my $exitcode = run [ $command, @args ], '>', \my $stdout, '2>', \my $stderr;
```

At this point, the two scalars `$stdout` and `$stderr` will now contain whatever the program wrote to STDOUT and STDERR respectively.